# Существует ли способ создания эффекта наклоненного `frosted glass` в CSS / SVG?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, filter

Я хочу сделать страницу-заставку.

У страницы будет один фон, который будет обрезан с левой стороны наклонной областью под углом 110 градусов от горизонтали.

Этот наклонный элемент будет размывать фон за ним и позволит размещать на нём, например текст. 
См. [Страницу ресурсов бренда YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/brand-resources/): вместо того, чтобы иметь простой белый фон слева, я бы хотел, чтобы это размыло фоновое изображение, которое находится под ним.

Я еще не нашел способ объединить всю найденную информацию так, чтобы она работала и поддерживалась большинством браузеров.

Например, я недавно попробовал `skewed div`, который делил фон с родительским контейнером, но `clip paths` CSS еще  не поддерживаются в полном объеме, и белый div не будет обрезать его для моего варианта использования.

Использование `SVG clip paths` и `filters`  (см. Ниже) приближает меня к решению, но, как вы можете видеть, я не знаю, как убедиться, что изображение и SVG заполняют экран и выравниваются с фоном позади него.

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;

  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  }
.splash {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/17/22/15/tree-3822149_960_720.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  svg {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="splash">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <polygon points="0,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
        <image clip-path="url('#clip')" filter="url('#blur')" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/17/22/15/tree-3822149_960_720.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54018409/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете рассмотреть `skew transform` без применения `clip-path`.
 Вот основной пример, где трюк заключается в том, чтобы указать правильное значение `background-position` для создания иллюзии одного изображения.

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=1069);
  background-position:left center;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.skew,
.skew::before{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:skewY(30deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-position:inherit;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.skew::before {
  content:"";
  transform:skewY(-30deg);
  filter:blur(10px);
  background-size:cover;
}

/*to illustrate the separation*/
.skew {
  border-top:1px solid;
}
/**/
.container {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:150px;
  padding-left:50px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=3)">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы перекос был responsive, вы можете добавить небольшой код JS, чтобы отрегулировать угол и всегда покрыть половину изображения:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = 300; /*the height of the box*/
document.querySelector('.box .skew').style.transform="skewY("+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
document.querySelector('.box .skew span').style.transform="skewY(-"+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    document.querySelector('.box .skew').style.transform="skewY("+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
    document.querySelector('.box .skew span').style.transform="skewY(-"+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
};
```

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=1069);
  background-position:left center;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.skew,
.skew span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:skewY(30deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-position:inherit;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.skew span{
  transform:skewY(-30deg);
  filter:blur(10px);
  background-size:cover;
}
/*to illustrate the separation*/
.skew {
  border-top:1px solid;
}
/**/
.container {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:150px;
  padding-left:50px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="skew"><span></span></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь то можно это сделать без использования js вообще: **смотрим на весь экран**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.item2 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, #fff 45%, transparent 45%);
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.item1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item1 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.item3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 50%;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.item3 p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.item3 a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.item3 a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item3 a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: 0.35s;
}

.item3 a:hover:before {
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://www.pethersolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/shutterstock_326441111.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3">
    <h3>О бренде YOUTUBE</h3>
    <p>Здесь представлена основная информация о бренде YouTube. <br>Если вы хотите использовать его элементы, помните, что <br>сначала требуется получить разрешение.</p>
    <a href="#">Оформить запрос на использование бренда</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Ссылка на полноэкранное ДЭМО](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/yGdmVZ)